# Require login for certain blueprints in Flask?

Tags: session, authentication, admin, flask

What's the common approach of adding access control to a blueprint in Flask?

For example I have a blueprint called `admin` with `url_prefix='/admin'`

How do I force all views under `/admin` must be authenticated superuser first?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found it http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/59/

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import redirect, request
from google.appengine.api import users

bp = Blueprint('admin', __name__)

@bp.before_request
def restrict_bp_to_admins():
    if not users.is_current_user_admin():
        return redirect(users.create_login_url(request.url))
```

Comment: What if I don't want my blueprint to explicitly depend on the authentication module? I only want the `app.register_blueprint` part to depend on auth so I can instantiate the same blueprint with multiple authentication backends?

Comment: @TamasHegedus you may add security before register_blueprint.

e.g. in case of rq-dashboard,

``
@rq_dashboard.blueprint.before_request
def restrict_bp_to_users():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))

app.register_blueprint(rq_dashboard.blueprint, url_prefix="/rq")
``

Answer (score 0):

http://packages.python.org/Flask-Principal/ will save you soul =)